# How to delete the exact element when there are multiple elements with same name?

Tags: java, jdom-2

Guys:

I have a problem to remove an element from a XML file with JDOM 2.5. The problem is: under the same parent element "ApproachDat", there are multiple elements with same name as "Notes", and I only want to delete some of them based on a given criteria. I have find qualified elements that I want to delete, but I notice JDOM 2.5 only provides removeChild, which removes the first found child with given name; or removeChildren, which removes all of children elements with given name. Is there anyway to remove the exact child element that qualifies a condition?

Thanks a lot!

Sam

Comment: Try using `removeContent(Filter<f> filter);` http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/filter/Filter.html if you haven't used `Filter` before

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! yes it is correct, and i can also use detach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the actual element you want to remove, remember that it is polymorphically a `Content` object. So you can use the `removeContent()` method that accepts a `Content` reference ([Javadoc](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#removeContent%28org.jdom2.Content%29)).